# What is the best strategy for loading metadata in mobile applications?

Tags: android, caching, retrofit2, metadata

My Android app needs to call some meta data from my backend server like config values, categories, image descriptions and more. The data does not change very often but sometimes I need to add values to the master data and need the app to pick it up (However even then the time is not that critical).

What is best practice for such a scenario? Loading the data every time it is needed seems bit overkill. Should I load it whenever the app is starting and use caching? More options?

I'm using retrofit 2 if this helps in finding a solution.

Comment: In my projects like yours, I firstly post a small IamHere data on SplashScreen. This action confirms that user is connected and able to reach my server. I also log device Info here. IamHere (static json file) returns data that is useful for deciding to fetch settings or some other configs. And I usually put a version number to settings. If settings version is different from my data in shared preferences, I fetch settings, else skip fetching settings. Also here I can be able to inform user if a new version is available and redirect to play store to update app.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use SharedPreferences (key - value) to save user information like security tokens, and user data. But if you need to save some static data like api url, api keys for using some services in your app, you could use resValues in build.gradle (where your put your dependencies).

**Example of sharedPreferences:**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
val content = pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
```

**Example saving static data in gradle:**

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            resValue "string", "url_api", "http://test.api.org/"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "url_api", "https://production.api.org/"
        }
    }
```

And when I need to call this url using retrofit I use this line of code:

```
val example = Retrofit.Builder()
.client(okHttpClient)
.baseUrl(application.getString(R.string.url_api)) // using resvalue from gradle
.addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
.build()
.create(ApropoApi::class.java)
```

for development I can use the debug resvalue, and after publishing my app it uses releases resvalue.

Depending of your business logic, you must decide what to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm currently storing the information in the sharedPreferences but my question is more related on the load strategy like when to call for static data and how often? (Periodic call, app startup call, whenever data is used call, ...)